# Ionic2-3 - Best way to save "game progress"

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm starting with Ionic and trying to figure it out, best practices and how the life cycle works, etc.

On a test project I'm working there's a small game capability, like a quiz or something.

Whats the correct way of saving the user progress and game settings? I don't have a backend to connect... Wondering if this Firebase is good to do this kind of stuff.

ps.: sorry for my english

Comment: This question has a variety of answers and depending on what you want to achieve, you need to be more specific. But since it's for study purpouses you can use firebase and you'll learn a new tool. If the game is offline and the user can't load the progress if he uninstall/install the game you can use any offline solution including local storage, if it's online you'll need a backend, even if it's BaaS like Firebase.

Comment: @GabrielBarreto I was thinking of making it mainly offline, but with user auth on firebase. In this aproach do you think local storage is my best call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use these: 
http://couchdb.apache.org/ 
and 
https://pouchdb.com/
I hope help you.